# Generic implementation for Java like List in C

Tags: c, generic-list

I have one requirement in one of my projects, where I have to deal with lots of data. Typically huge, dynamic arrays in C.

I searched but I have not been able to find what I need.
I am looking for a usable library, which encapsulates the details of list implementation in C, and provides various functions for List manipulation.

I am aware that we can create such implementation in C, using pointers.

I have followed below links:

[C generic linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173480/c-generic-linked-list)

[Generic list manipulation function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326202/generic-list-manipulation-function-in-c)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I have mentioned that I looked for such tool. In case that is present, and I am not aware of, I would really appreciate such help. But I am not asking anyone to search one for me.
I just want to know if someone knows of any

Comment: If you want a generic library, use a language that supports generic programming. C isn't one, but there seems to be one or two languages that are advertised as "the next C" or something. One of them just might fit the bill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this small library is what you need.

It is a generic list implementation in C. [glist](https://github.com/rajan-goswami/glist)

Comment: This library seems to a good LIB.